# My friend thinks the WCC has 14 games in a short amount of time with the purpose to induce player errors. Is that true at all?

Tags: world-championship

For some reason, my friend believes that the format of the World Chess Championship is made in such a way with the purpose of increasing the amount of errors by the players. Is there any trutto this claim, and why?

Comment: Why does your friend think the format induces errors?

Answer (score 4):

The change in time controls from the 2018 match (which had an increment from move 1) to the 2021 match (no increment until move 60) is widely acknowledged as having the goal of increasing the likelihood of time trouble and hence mistakes.  This is exactly what happened in game 6, and Magnus acknowledged this point in the press conference.

Some people have also suggested that the decrease in rest days was also intended to make the players more likely to make errors.  This is less clear-cut, because the increase in number of games is also a good reason to have fewer rest days.

Comment: Actually, it's completely clear cut. It's all for more decisive games. Dvorkovich is on record saying so (check for example his interview for Chess24 with Tania Sachdev).

Comment: I was partly going off Magnus's opinion from the press conference that fewer rest days as such wasn't a problem, but that having a marathon game did effect the play in the games between that game and the rest day.  If I've found the correct Dvorkovich quote, it's a little ambiguous to me whether it's the lack of rest days as such that he's talking about or rather that the key thing is having more games.

Comment: "The key difference is 14 classical time control games instead of 12. With more games that we have now, the probability of error increases. Moreover, tension is known to go up as the number of rest days goes down. We will actually have two rest days per week, unlike the previous one rest day following every two games [...] This is to bring up the rate of decisive games compared to the 2018 London match between Magnus Carlsen and Fabiano Caruana, in which all 12 classical control games ended in a draw. I hope that Dubai will bring us more decisive games, after all."

Comment: Right! Since you adduce the full quote, perhaps it belongs in your answer. (on Chess.SE comments are not sacred)